# Literature request for polynomial approximation

Tags: polynomials, reference-request, approximation-theory

I would like to learn how to fit a multivariable polynomial through a set of data (surface fitting, volume fitting, and so on). I know how to do it if the polynomial is dependent on only one variable, but I would like to know how to generalize the approach. So far I searched online in approximation theory books, but I wasn't able to find this. Please recommend literature on this topic.